# Angular 6 Routing: Different parameters to Same Page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following subset of Routes:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'plans', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'plan/edit/:id',
    component: EditPlanPageComponent,
    resolve: { plan: PlanResolver, planContext: PlanContextResolver },
  },
  {
    path: 'plan/edit/pn/:pn',
    component: EditPlanPageComponent,
    resolve: { plan: PlanResolver, planContext: PlanContextResolver },
  },
  ];
```

As you can see Im going to the same place from *plan/edit/**:id*** and *plan/edit/pn/**:pn***.  There are several other params as well. What the users are looking for is a few different ways to be directed to the same page.
This doesn't scale well.

Im unsure if there is a mechanism to handle this scenario, or if i am supposed to handle that in the resolver. Is there a built in tool for this, and is it supposed to be handled by the resolver?  Another way to ask this is the following: Can this be achieved with rerouting or children, or something ive entirely missed?

For the record what im building in the resolver looks like this:

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    let pn = +route.paramMap.get('pn');
    //Param 3, 4,5 .....



    // Determine which param has value

    //Get plan With appropriate logic based upon value


    return of(this.plan$);

  }
```

**Edit** To address some confusion - Im not hitting a bug so much as I *think* im doing something in a way that wasn't intended that happens to work okay.

Comment: Its all working, It just seems like a hacky solution.

Answer (score 3):

Order matters, and Angular will go with the first match. Therefore, this simple reordering will fix your problem.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'plans', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'plan/edit/pn/:pn',
    component: EditPlanPageComponent,
    resolve: { plan: PlanResolver, planContext: PlanContextResolver },
  },
  {
    path: 'plan/edit/:id',
    component: EditPlanPageComponent,
    resolve: { plan: PlanResolver, planContext: PlanContextResolver },
  }
];
```

From https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration:

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
>   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
>   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every
>   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Comment: This didn't directly answer my question, but it did directly solve a related issue i was having. I dont know about protocol on if i should take this as the answer or not.

Comment: @Seth You're right. I just saw the title and your snippet and assumed what your problem was. Sorry that I didn't fully read your question.